# ¿Como crear un bitmap de color blanco a partir de un array de bytes?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Estoy trabajando en android y deseo crear un bitmap de color blanco a partir de un array de bytes pero no se como se haga, por el momento he intentado esto

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[10000];

 for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++){
       b[i]= 0 & 0xff;
 }

 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
 this.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: al lanzar la app no me muestra nada incluso le puse un fondo negro en el layout

Comment: no entiendo la parte "a partir de un array de bytes" como es que quieres lograr esto ? cual es el objetivo de la app y que obtienes con ese array